# Request Aborted | Stop ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

Server - node.js I send the file to the server with ajax request, the progress of the download is displayed. There is a button that stops this ajax request (xhr.abort ()). After pressing the "stop" button, the server crashes with request aborted. What to do?

```
app.post("/blog/add", function (req, res, next) {
    //Проанализируем загрузку файла
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    var wayImage = "/files/";

    form.on('part', function (part) {
        var path = './public/files/' + part.filename;
        wayImage += part.filename;
        var out = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        part.pipe(out);
    });

    form.on('close', function () {
        //Отправка ссылки на картинку
        res.send(wayImage);
    });

    form.on('error', function () {
        console.log('error');
    });

    form.parse(req);
});
```

Comment: you should provide code samples

Comment: added...........

Comment: i get this https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty/issues/27 i think its a way to solve your problem

Comment: there are discussions about stopping at the check

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60lrc.png